# Fluent NHibernate - 1:1 Relationship with Nullable Field

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Given the following model, I want to be able to enter a new `WriteOffApprovalUser` and have the `Employee` field be null. This is a 1:1 or null relationship.

```
public class WriteOffApprovalUser
{
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmployeeStatusCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string Division { get; set; }
    public virtual string Department { get; set; }
    public virtual string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string DeskLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual string MailID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string PreferredName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fax { get; set; }
    public virtual string SecCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string SupervisorID { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**Class Maps**

```
public class WriteOffApprovalUserMap : ClassMap<WriteOffApprovalUser>
{
    public WriteOffApprovalUserMap()
    {
        Table("WRITEOFF_APPROVAL_USER");

        Id(x => x.UserName).Column("USER_NAME");

        //Map(x => x.Employee).Nullable();

        HasOne(x => x.Employee)
            .Class<Employee>()
            .Constrained()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .PropertyRef("UserId");
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("ADP_EMPLOYEE");

        Id(x => x.EmployeeID).Column("EMPLID").GeneratedBy.Native("");

        Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("FIRST_NAME");
        Map(x => x.LastName).Column("LAST_NAME");
        Map(x => x.PreferredName).Column("PREFERRED_NAME");
        Map(x => x.UserId).Column("USER_ID");
    }
}
```

**Query/Save**

```
using (var session = SessionProvider.GetSession())
        {
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var user = new WriteOffApprovalUser() { UserName = "SAMSTR" };

                session.Save(user);

                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
```

This complains that `Employee` is null. How do I specify that Employee can be null?

Also, do all `Id` fields have to be integral? A lot of the keys on our tables are strings.

Answer (score -1):

First off all if you put it as 1:1 it shouldn't be NULL because it's not correct design.

But here is an example of how to do so:

***1) One way***

```
HasOne(x => x.Employee)
            .Class<Employee>().Nullable().NotFound.Ignore().PropertyRef("UserId");
```

***2) Second way***

```
References(x => x.Category).Column("UserId").Nullable().NotFound.Ignore();
```

Comment: OK, but really what is happening is that there is a `Employee` already and I just want to enter the `WriteOffApprovalUser` and then later when I query the relationship is there. I dont want to add the `Employee` side, but there is always only one `Employee` to one `WriteOffApprovalUser` and vice-versa. Make sense?

Comment: I get this error:`'FluentNHibernate.Mapping.OneToOnePart<SAIF.Data.Model.Employee.Employee>' does not contain a definition for 'Nullable' and no extension method 'Nullable' accepting a first argument of type 'FluentNHibernate.Mapping.OneToOnePart<SAIF.Data.Model.Employee.Employee>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You mean Lazy load? For performance issues or by design you don't need this `Entity`

Comment: Neither `NotFound` or `Ignore` exist??

Comment: Dude what version do you use.